# Extracting from the data frame produced using GageRR/GageRRDesign in R

Tags: r, dataframe

How do I extract the 'VarCompContrib" column in the data frame produced using the gageRR function in R?

This is for a GageRR analysis of a measurement system.  I'm trying to make a very user friendly program where other people can just enter the information required, like number of operators, parts, and measurements, as well as the measurements themselves, and output the correct analysis. I'm gonna use an if-statement later on to do the "analysis" portion, but I am having trouble actually managing the data frame produced with gageRR.

```
library(MASS)
library(Rsolnp)
library(qualityTools)

design = gageRRDesign(Operators=3, Parts=10, Measurements=2, randomize=FALSE)

response(design) = c(23,22,22,22,22,25,23,22,23,22,20,22,22,22,24,25,27,28,      
23,24,23,24,24,22,22,22,24,23,22,24,20,20,25,24,22,24,21,20,21,22,21,22,21,
                     21,24,27,25,27,23,22,25,23,23,22,22,23,25,21,24,23)
gdo=gageRR(design)

plot(gdo)
```

I am looking to get a 7 number column vector under `VarCompContrib`

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you can look at the structure of `gdo` with `str(gdo)`. From there, we see that `Varcomp` is a slot, so we can access it with `gdo@Varcomp` and just convert it to a `data.frame`:

```
library(qualityTools)

design <- gageRRDesign(Operators = 3, Parts = 10, Measurements = 2, randomize = FALSE)

response(design) <- c(
  23,22,22,22,22,25,23,22,23,22,20,22,22,22,24,25,27,28,23,24,23,24,24,22,22,22,24,23,22,24,
  20,20,25,24,22,24,21,20,21,22,21,22,21,21,24,27,25,27,23,22,25,23,23,22,22,23,25,21,24,23
)

gdo <- gageRR(design)

data.frame(gdo@Varcomp)
#   totalRR repeatability reproducibility         a a_b     bTob totalVar
# 1 1.66441      1.209028       0.4553819 0.4553819   0 1.781211 3.445621
```